# how to query posts by category and tag?

Tags: query-posts, tags

I am trying to show a list of posts that are related to category X and tag Y.
I've tried the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tag_id' => $tag_id,
    'cat' => $cat_id,
);
query_posts($args);
```

but it doesn't work correctly and returns all the posts in the co\ategory.

Would love to hear any insight you might have

Comment: I think with query_posts() you can only make use of category or tag. I'm not sure, but maybe the use of the function is limited to that which would mean that this is correctly working but it doesn't do what you want to do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Edit: See below for proper way to query category and tag intersections.

```
global $wp_query;
        $args = array(
        'category__and' => 'category', //must use category id for this field
        'tag__in' => 'post_tag', //must use tag id for this field
        'posts_per_page' => -1); //get all posts

$posts = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($posts as $post) :
  //do stuff 
     endforeach;
```

Answer (score 5):

This code works:

```
$args = array(
    'tag' => get_queried_object()->slug, // If permalink like example.com/tag/example-tag, etc.
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category', // Taxonomy, in my case I need default post categories
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'interior', // Your category slug (I have a category 'interior')
        ),
        ) 
); // Get all posts
$posts_new = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is bug in WordPress that has been commented on elsewhere, try using the name of the tag rather than the ID then it should work:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tag' => 'review',
    'cat' => 9,
);
query_posts($args);
```

Let us know how you get on, not sure what happens with tags with multiple words in the name.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled into this same issue and resolved it by making a MySQL request .

in short : 
get_post($args) will return you posts who have the category=MyCategory **OR** the tag=MyTag.

what you want is to change your **OR** to **AND** .

my logic was to go straight with a MySQL Query:

- Query 1 = Select all the posts who has the category MyCat
- Query 2 = Select all the posts who has the tag MyTag
- FinalLY :  Select all the posts who are in Query 1 AND Query 2 .

I used [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) instead of query_post();

**A bit of code** *(returning published posts with category MyCat and tag MyTag )*:

```
    $query_byTag="
            SELECT wp_posts.ID
            FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms
            WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
            AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
            AND wp_terms.name = 'MyTag'";

    $query_byCat="
            SELECT wp_posts.ID
            FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms
            WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
            AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
            AND wp_terms.name = 'MyCat'";

$query ="
            SELECT      wp_posts.post_title AS title , 
                        wp_posts.post_content AS content,
                        wp_posts.post_date AS blogdate 
            FROM wp_posts
            WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
            AND wp_posts.ID IN (".$query_byTag.")
            AND wp_posts.ID IN (".$query_byCat.")
            ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC ";

$result= $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

This is a dirty way to do it but I hope it helps =)

Comment: This is much more easily accomplished with [`WP_Query` and a `tax_query` AND relationship](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), no need for raw SQL.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to do raw queries in WordPress to achieve this.

Comment: also I think this is wrong: "AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id" because you're skipping the wp_term_taxonomy table entirely.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_name
FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_terms.name = "MY TAG"
```

Comment: Code only answers rarely meet quality standards. Please edit your answer and include notes / commentary on how this solves the original issue along with how / where to implement it.

Comment: This is much more easily accomplished with WP_Query and a tax_query AND relationship, no need for raw SQL.