# URL scheme to retrieve tag archive by ID

Tags: tags, archives, id

You can retrieve a category archive by using a URL scheme like `https://example.com/?cat=123`. This even works if pretty permalinks are enabled.

What is the equivalent query string for tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to query posts by category and tag?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/how-to-query-posts-by-category-and-tag)

Comment: You should look up the documentation for `WP_Query` parameters, as they're the same as what you're using here, though you'd be better using the pretty permalink versions of tag ID archives. Also, `get_term_link()` is your friend

Comment: @jgraup This is a different question.

Comment: To answer you question, there is no `cat` equivalent for tags, and tags links are in the form `tag=slug`

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you, but the `WP_Query` parameters suggest that something like `https://example.com/?tag_id=123` should work, and it doesn't.

Comment: @NabilKadimi Thank you very much, that's the answer I was looking for. Even though I was hoping there would be another solution.

Comment: @Florian The other solution would be to write your own custom rewrite rule using `add_rewrite_rule()` and map that to your desired `tag_id` parameter