# Count how many posts have a specified tag AND category

Tags: categories, tags, count

I know how to count how many posts has a certain tag, or category

For example:

```
$term_slug = 'some-post-tag';
$term = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $post_tag);
echo $term->count;
```

**BUT!**
Is there anyway to count how many posts that have a tag **AND** a specified category?

I want to count how many posts that have the tag(slug) *"cat"* and the category slug *"allowpost"*

Is this even possible?

Edit: if possible, it would be good if this is manageable via some solution similarly my first script, because this is going to be used on search result pages, and ***different post pages***, so adding something to the loop itself won't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue, originally created by Mr. Prashant Singh @ [WordPress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/count-number-of-posts-with-a-specified-tag-and-category/)

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND', // only posts that have both taxonomies will return.
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => 'your-tag-slug', //cat
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => 'your-category-slug', //allowpost
    ),
  ),
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
$count = count($posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use WP_Query and specifically a [tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters):

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'allow-list' ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'cats' ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $count = $the_query->found_posts;
      echo 'Post count: ' . $count;
     // echo '<ul>';

     // while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      //  $the_query->the_post();
       // echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
     // }
    //  echo '</ul>';
   } else {
     echo 'No posts found';
   }
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: how do I echo it?

Comment: Because I'm not seeing anything (I might add that I'm pretty new at php and WordPress..

Comment: I added a line to echo $count . I've also added a regular "loop" so you can see where the post content could be displayed. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ for all the many options of what you can query and https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/ for what you can display within The Loop.

Comment: but this script it lists all the posts?

Comment: I was thinking about a php snippet that simply displays how many posts that has the correct attributes, not displaying or listing them..

Comment: I have commented out the code that shows the posts themselves, now it should just say "Post count: " and the count.

Comment: Thx a  lot, now I just have to figure out how to put it inside the loop. The original code I showed could be entered anywhere, but this must be placed inside the loop?

Comment: I would like to thank you for your time, but I didn't get it to work, and as I describe in the updated question, it wouldn't work since I'm having different post pages for different animal. Is it possible to solve this somehow via a script like the one I wrote?

Comment: Without knowing where you're placing your code it's hard to write this for you. Can you update your original question to include all the code (the loop, etc) and where you want to display the count? @JoBe

Comment: that's the hard part, as you probably guessed, I'm not a pro. I'm using elementor as a builder. There I'm using a widget that displays posts. There I can setup what to display, and I've then selected that it should display the posts that are tagged cat, and are in the category *allowed to be showed* (allowpost), so I don't really know how the loop works. The code I'm using to display number of posts with the tag *cat* is just simply inserted in the page as php code via xyz php plug-in.

Comment: You gave up on me I guess...

Comment: @JoBe sorry, I've been busy on another project, haven't had time to devote to this. You might want to start a new question. I'm still unclear on what you're actually trying to achieve, whether the count should be for the posts you are displaying via the widget or globally how many posts in your entire site have both a specific tag + category, for instance.  Maybe this answer will help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/how-to-query-posts-by-category-and-tag Sorry I don't have more time!

Comment: We all lack the time we need, somehow. It's okey, you have put some ideas in my head, but as I wrote, I'm a newbie.  What I was after was:  if I count all posts that have the tag "cat" I maybe get 100, but i only want to count those who also are in the category "allowpost". That simple, no need to display posts or anything, I just want the number of posts that contains both the tag "cat" and category "allowpost" and store it in a variable ($nocats) so I can echo the result.. maybe I expressed me clumsy previously..